# Kali on 32gb flash drive displays 67gb storage

Tags: filesystems, kali-linux, usb-drive, disk

I'm new to linux and how it works. I recently installed a kali linux image onto a 32gb flash drive and stuck it into my pc and booted from it. All went well, and so I ran the `df` command and got this result:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           788M   18M  770M   3% /run
/dev/sdb1       4.0G  2.7G  1.4G  67% /lib/live/mount/persistence/sdb1
/dev/loop0      2.4G  2.4G     0 100% /lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /lib/live/mount/overlay
/dev/sdb2        20G  5.2G   13G  29% /lib/live/mount/persistence/sdb2
overlay          20G  5.2G   13G  29% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.9G   98M  3.8G   3% /tmp
tmpfs           788M   12K  788M   1% /run/user/131
tmpfs           788M   40K  788M   1% /run/user/0
total            67G   16G   49G  25% -
```

So how is the total size 67gb?

Also, what are all of these partitions? I would have thought there would be just two: the system, and the persistence file. Is there a reason that kali is partitioned into this many pieces, and is there documentation on which each of them do/are?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Linux... it will be good if you get to know your `man` pages. There is a lot of information there.... also do a little web researching, All of this information is 'out there somewhere'

You are not looking at disk usage but total filesystem usage.

If you read around a little you will see that all of your [tmpfs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html) exist in memory and that your [overlay](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Overlay_filesystem) is a mapping of `persistence`onto non-writable layers.

[udev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991533/0-usage-on-udev-dev-partition) is a particular type of tmpfs

Since you know that your SD card is mounted at `/dev/sdb`your usage on that device is just the sum of the writable 'persistence' allocations to that device (/dev/sdb1 & sdb2, 20G+4.8G) plus the non-writable `squashfs` image which is also on /dev/sdb but is mounted at `loop0` (2.4G).